# Using "qué" or "quién" when talking about people

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática

Imagine for a moment you know who stole your car (some thiefs for example):

> Sabemos qué personas lo hicieron.

The above sentence is the same as saying:

> Sabemos quiénes lo hicieron. (Persons are imply)

In both sentences we are talking about people, so my question is, if I use this form:

> Sabemos quiénes personas lo hicieron.

Is this correct and/or legal? I mean using "quiénes" despite "personas" being implied?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Quién](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=quien)** is a **interrogative/exclamative pronoun**, so it must resplace a noun.

On the other hand **[qué](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=que)** can be an **interrogative/exclamative pronoun** (when referring to things) or and **interrogative/exclamative adjective** (when referring to people or things). So as we are talking about people it can only be an adjective so it has to go with a name.

You can find a complete explanation from RAE about the use of **[quién](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=qui%E9n)** here and about the use of **[qué](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=qu%E9)** here.

So for example the sentence you gave:

> Sabemos **qué personas** lo hicieron. (Qué used as an adjective: **Correct**)
>
> Sabemos **quiénes** lo hicieron. (Quiénes used as a pronoun: **Correct**)
>
> Sabemos **quiénes personas** lo hicieron.* (Quiénes used as an adjective: **Incorrect**)
>
> Sabemos **qué** lo hicieron.* (Qué used as a pronoun, replacing people: **Incorrect**)